# Compress Image quality without resizing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image, compression

I want to compress that image quality without re-sizing it. I have already gone through many posts related to compression and re-sizing but i'm not getting the exact thing which i'm looking for.I am using this code :

```
- (UIImage *)compressImage:(UIImage *)image withCompressionFactor:(int)compressionFactor
    {
      double factor = 1.0;
      double adjustment = 1.0/ sqrt(2.0);
      CGSize size = image.size;
      CGSize currentSize = size;
      UIImage *currentImage = image;
      NSData *imageData;
     int requiredLength;

      imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

     requiredLength = imageData.length/compressionFactor; // (compressionfactor = 3)

     while( imageData.length >= requiredLength)
     {
      factor *= adjustment;
  currentSize = CGSizeMake(roundf(size.width * factor), roundf(size.height *   factor));
    currentImage = [image resizedImage:currentSize interpolationQuality:0.1]; 
        imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(currentImage);
  }

return currentImage;
}
```

In this case my image size and quality of image is reducing because of re-sizing. Is there any way to compress the image quality without re-sizing it? Any hint or Solution?

Comment: With `PNG` I don't think its possible, but for `JPEG` its possible. `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(currentImage, 0.1);`

Comment: @iphonic - Thanks for your response. I have already added this thing for JPEG but i'm facing problem with PNG format.